Problem with std::unique_ptr and dangling pointer
When I run this code:
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() = 0;
};
class B : public A {
private:
  int b0;
public:
  B(const B& b) { b0 = b.get_b0(); }
  B(const int& b0) : b0(b0) {}
  std:: unique_ptr<A> clone() { return std::make_unique<B>(*this); }
  const int& get_b0() const { return b0; }
  int& get_b0() { return b0; }
};
class box {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> o;
public: 
  box(const box& sp) { o = sp.o->clone(); }
  box(std::unique_ptr<A> o)  : o(std::move(o)) {}
  std::unique_ptr<A> get_o() { return o->clone(); }
};
void foo(std::unique_ptr<box> sp) {
  std::unique_ptr<A> o = sp->get_o();
if(const B *ptr1 = dynamic_cast<const B*>(o.get()))
  std::cout << ptr1->get_b0() << std::endl;
if(const B *ptr = dynamic_cast<const B*>(sp->get_o().get()))
  std::cout << ptr->get_b0() << std::endl;
}
int main() {
  B b(100);
  box sp(std::make_unique<B>(b));
  foo(std::make_unique<box>(sp));
  return 0;
}

The output is:
100  
3579964222 (some random integer!!!)

If I ditch std::unique_ptr, and replace it with std::shared_ptr, the code starts working. But in my use case, shared_ptr may lead to problems, as changing one object might affect others.
I like to know how I can fix this code? And if the way I am using clone() is good code practice or not?

Your class A must have a virtual destructor. That's the most important rule when passing ownership to an object via polymorphic base class. Attempting to delete through a base class pointer (whether with delete or indirectly through unique_ptr<A>) will otherwise cause undefined behavior.

I would have killed to have had tools like these sanitizers when I was a kid learning this stuff: https://godbolt.org/z/E5vz33Ehr This time it can't tell you exactly what you got wrong, but it should get the ball rolling.

What basically happens in second case is that std::unique_ptr returned by get_o() is deleted after condition is checked, so you pointer ptr will point to invalid memory. I'm not sure why you need to clone object, but if you do, then don't throw it away... If you just need to access data. then don't clone object, but rather return const reference.

And once again, the sanitizer can tell you you what sklott just did: https://godbolt.org/z/9vGrrn5GE Get up-to-date tools with as many bells and whistles as you can get and make use of them. They will save you tons of time.

It's undefined behavior, ptr is a dangling pointer.
The expression sp->get_o() produces a temporary object of std::unique_ptr<A>.
The C++ standard says in class.temporary#4 that:

Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

And "full-expression" is defined in intro.execution#12.3 as:

A full-expression is

...
an init-declarator or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
...


Hence, the full-expression here is dynamic_cast<const B*>(sp->get_o().get())), after which is evaluated, the temporary object std::unique_ptr<A> returned by sp->get_o() will be destroyed, and the object it points will be deleted in its destructor. So ptr becomes a dangling pointer.
To fix it, just extend the lifetime of the object returned by sp->get_o():
std::unique_ptr<A> o1 = sp->get_o();
if (const B* ptr = dynamic_cast<const B*>(o1.get())) {
    std::cout << ptr->get_b0() << std::endl;
}

